# How to put php variable inside php variable with a javascript value

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I need to put php variable inside php variable with javascript value, here is some of my codes that I tried but doesnt work (its file is in .php):

```
$rowEmail = "EmailTest";

$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#reminderModal').modal('toggle'); console.log('"echo $rowEmail;"');</script>";

$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#reminderModal').modal('toggle'); console.log('".echo $rowEmail."');</script>";

$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#reminderModal').modal('toggle'); console.log('".$rowEmail."');</script>";
```

Comment: "doesnt work" ? Got only one JS line ?

Comment: <script> var email =  <?=$rowEmail?>;  console.log(email) </script>

Comment: This is vulnerable to JS and HTML injections (at least). Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output literals that are safe to use in JavaScript context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#reminderModal').modal('toggle'); console.log('" . $rowEmail . "');</script>";
```

You don't need the echos, just concatanate the string.

If it is not a must for the love of what's good in this world do not store tags in variables like that. Makes it incredibly hard to read and debug later on.

Comment: Isn't that the 3rd thing he did?

Comment: yes, but he didn't output(echo) the string afterwards, so nothing happened ...

Comment: It is and it works just fine. Provided he included the jQuery library properly.

Answer (score 2):

You have some misunderstanding on how to output data via PHP. Need something like:

```
$rowEmail = "EmailTest";

$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('". $rowEmail ."');</script>";
echo $script;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your last line is correct I don't know you why say it doesn't work,
I've tried it and it works :

```
<?php
$rowEmail = "EmailTest";
$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#reminderModal').modal('toggle'); console.log('".$rowEmail."');</script>";

echo $script;
// displays <script type='text/javascript'>$('#reminderModal').modal('toggle'); console.log('EmailTest');</script>
```

Comment: Didn't work, because $script was not echoed afterwards ...